# How do I get Google Apps Script to do SHA-256 encryption?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, sha256, sha

I need to encrypt strings with TEXT input, 1 round, HEX output, SHA-256 encryption. Which should be a string of characters of length 64.
Every SHA-256 encryption module I've tried in Google Apps Script docs returns a set of numbers. For example.

```
function SHA256() {
    var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature("this is my input",
                                                 "my key - use a stronger one",
                                                 Utilities.Charset.US_ASCII);
Logger.log(signature);
    }
```

Outputs

```
[53, -75, -52, -25, -47, 86, -21, 14, -2, -57, 5, -13, 24, 105, -2, -84, 127, 115, -40, -75, -93, -27, -21, 34, -55, -117, -36, -103, -47, 116, -55, -61]
```

I haven't seen anything in the docs or elsewhere that specifies every parameter I'm going for outlined above for GAS. I wouldn't mind a deeper explanation of putting it together from scratch if that is what is required. I'm encrypting info to send to Facebook for Offline Conversions for ads. How does Facebook decrypt the encrypted strings?
Google Apps Script docs
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computeHmacSha256Signature(String,String,Charset)

Comment: [Edit] to show sample input and output

Comment: Is SHA-256, Hex, 1 round, Text input written out somewhere in a function in Javascript that I can just copy and paste into my script? This function, for example https://geraintluff.github.io/sha256/   ? I'm really not even sure how this works, how the receiver decrypts the string tbh.

Comment: That's what it outputs. What do you expect it to output? What's the expected result for a given input?

Comment: "What do you expect it to output?" A string of characters of length 64.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`̶U̶t̶i̶l̶i̶t̶i̶e̶s̶.̶c̶o̶m̶p̶u̶t̶e̶H̶m̶a̶c̶S̶h̶a̶2̶5̶6̶S̶i̶g̶n̶a̶t̶u̶r̶e̶` `Utilities.computeDigest()`returns an array of bytes (8-bit integers). If you want to convert that array to a string composed of hexadecimal characters you'll have to do it manually as follows:

```js
/** @type Byte[] */
var signature = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, value);

/** @type String */
var hexString = signature
    .map(function(byte) {
        // Convert from 2's compliment
        var v = (byte < 0) ? 256 + byte : byte;

        // Convert byte to hexadecimal
        return ("0" + v.toString(16)).slice(-2);
    })
    .join("");
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a dumb question, but how does my receiver of this, the person I send the encrypted string to, how do they decrypt the string? How do they get the key?

Comment: You would also need to prepad each byte with `0`, if `toString(16)` returns a single digit instead of a double. Also, the byte array values are signed(+-). It needs to be unsigned

Comment: @Hugh Signature is a one way hash.  You can't decrypt it

Comment: This answer isn't quite giving me what I get from the jsSHA("SHA-256", "TEXT", 1) npm module. A dozen or so dashes in your answer's output.

Comment: @TheMaster I'm just trying to follow the instructions here to send data to Facebook. I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I'm sure they don't want random strings rather than email addresses. https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2018/05/29/send-offline-conversions/

Comment: @Hugh it's not random. It's a signature. It's proof that you know the email address. Facebook also knows the address and the Facebook's hash  and your hash will be the same. But anyone who hacks the message in between communication cannot decipher the actual address from the hash.

Comment: @TheMaster I see now. A hash of 'abc' is always the same string for anyone hashing this way so the person on the other end can compare to their hashes. I've ended up using the long JS function in this link since it gives me what I want. https://geraintluff.github.io/sha256/

Comment: @HughMungus If you just needed to generate an SHA-256 hash then use `Utilities.computeDigest()` instead. Updating the script (again).

Comment: FYI for those coming here trying to SHA256 hash user info to send to Facebook Custom audiences, this answer is the way to go. Thank you @TheAddonDepot

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pair of functions to generate a SHA-256 hash as a hex string:

```js
function Sha256Hash(value) {
  return BytesToHex(
    Utilities.computeDigest(
      Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, value));
}

function BytesToHex(bytes) {
  let hex = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    let b = parseInt(bytes[i]);
    if (b < 0) {
      c = (256+b).toString(16);
    } else {
      c = b.toString(16);
    }
    if (c.length == 1) {
      hex.push("0" + c);
    } else {
      hex.push(c);
    }
  }
  return hex.join("");
}
```

It turns out that the `bytes[]` type is usable as a normal `Array` and so I took advantage of that when writing `BytesToHex()`.

There must be more elegant ways but I took this a bit further and managed to derive a correct signature for calling the AWS API:

```js
// Google Apps Script version of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-javascript
function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
  const kDate = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
  Logger.log("kDate    = '" + BytesToHex(kDate) + "'");
  const kRegion = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(Utilities.newBlob(regionName).getBytes(), kDate);
  Logger.log("kRegion  = '" + BytesToHex(kRegion) + "'");
  const kService = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(Utilities.newBlob(serviceName).getBytes(), kRegion);
  Logger.log("kService = '" + BytesToHex(kService) + "'");
  const kSigning = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(Utilities.newBlob("aws4_request").getBytes(), kService);
  Logger.log("kSigning = '" + BytesToHex(kSigning) + "'");
  return kSigning;
}

function Sha256Hmac(value, key) {
  return BytesToHex(Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(Utilities.newBlob(value).getBytes(), key));
}
```